# Call activity when on notification tap event

Tags: android, push-notification

I want to call the activity when user pull down the notification and tap on that notification. How can I do that?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Call `setLatestEventInfo()` on the `Notification` object, supplying a `PendingIntent` that will start your activity when they tap on your entry in the notification drawer. Here is [a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Notifications/Notify1/) demonstrating this.

Comment: I can start activity when clicked the notification on notification bar. But looks like It create new activity although current activity is running now. I tried to pass Flag into `Intent` when call `PendingIntent` but looks like not worked. So how close current activity before create new activity when clicked notification?

Comment: @HuyTower: `setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK  | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK)` on your `Intent` should work.

Comment: @CommonsWare: Works perfect for me!

Answer (score 11):

Assuming that `notif` is your `Notification` object:

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(), ActivityToStart.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this.getApplicationContext(), 0, notificationIntent, 0);
notif.contentIntent = contentIntent;
```

Comment: I can start activity when clicked the notification on notification bar. But looks like It create new activity although current activity is running now. I tried to pass Flag into `Intent` when call `PendingIntent` but looks like not worked. So how close current activity before create new activity when clicked notification?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code to call activity when notification is clicked

```
Notification notif = new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,"List of Contacts...", System.currentTimeMillis());
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context,AllContacts.class);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,            notificationIntent, 0);
notif.setLatestEventInfo(context, from, message, contentIntent);
nm.notify(1, notif);
```

Comment: I can start activity when clicked the notification on notification bar. But looks like It create new activity although current activity is running now. I tried to pass Flag into `Intent` when call `PendingIntent` but looks like not worked. So how close current activity before create new activity when clicked notification?